# KDB issue running query on server

Tags: kdb

I am new to KDB and I am trying to run the following command:

```
`F xasc ([] inst:insts; F:{[dmin; dmax;inst]
      (first exec (sum n where sprd > {[x]: first exec minpxincr from instinfo where inst = x}[inst]) % sum(n) from
      select n:count i by sprd:ask-bid from
      (
      {[dmin;dmax;inst] aj[ `seq; select seq from trade where date within (dmin;dmax),sym={[x;dmin;dmax]:exec first sym from `v xdesc select v:sum siz by sym from trade where date within (dmin;dmax), sym2inst[sym] = x}[inst;dmin;dmax];
      select seq,bid,ask from quote where date within (dmin;dmax),sym={[x;dmin;dmax]:exec first sym from `v xdesc select v:sum siz by sym from trade where date within (dmin;dmax), sym2inst[sym] = x}[inst;dmin;dmax]
      ]}
      [dmin; dmax; inst]))} [2020.10.22;2020.10.29;] each insts)
```

The idea is the following:

a/
`` {[x;dmin;dmax]:exec first sym from `v xdesc select v:sum siz by sym from trade where date within (dmin;dmax), sym2inst[sym] = x} ``
returns the most actively traded symbol for a given instrument.

b/ We compute, for each instrument, the fraction of trades which spread is above the minimum price increment for its most actively traded symbol (minpxincr, selected from the table instinfo).

I believe that my code is correct since it is working for a small number of instruments. However, when I want to apply it to the whole insts list, I am getting a connection interruption error.

`kdb+ : stop` or
`Not connected to kdb+ server`

Could anyone help me with alternatives / improvements to this syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The server process likely has a timeout applied and your query is exceeding it

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/cmdline/#-t-timeout

A `stop` error is thrown when you exceed the limit

[https://code.kx.com/q/basics/errors/#:~:text=stop,%2DT](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/errors/#:%7E:text=stop,%2DT)

If you tried to run one `inst` at a time over the handle then it may run.

```
h:hopen `::server:1234
insts:`a`b`c //local list to run through
data:{h(`function;2020.10.22;2020.10.29;x)} each insts
`F xasc ([] inst:insts; F:data)
```

Your code is very nested which makes it hard to read.

Breaking it out will make it easier to follow and also make refactoring and improving it much easier too: (note: use better names than `f1` etc in reality)

```
//In your code this was all duplicate 2 times. Reuse a single function instead
//Could you run this function once for all insts? 
f3:{[x;dmin;dmax]
     exec first sym from `v xdesc select v:sum siz by sym from trade where date within (dmin;dmax), sym2inst[sym] = x
     };

//Does aj[`seq`sym .. work for you? faster? memory an issue?
f2:{[dmin;dmax;inst] 
    aj[ `seq; select seq from trade where date within (dmin;dmax),sym=f3[inst;dmin;dmax];
             select seq,bid,ask from quote where date within (dmin;dmax),sym=f3[inst;dmin;dmax]
      ]};
      
f1:{[dmin; dmax;inst]
      first exec (sum n where sprd > {[x] first exec minpxincr from instinfo where inst = x}[inst]) % sum(n) from
      select n:count i by sprd:ask-bid from f2[dmin; dmax; inst]}
      
`F xasc ([] inst:insts; F:f1[2020.10.22;2020.10.29] each insts)
```

Rather than looping through `each insts` you may be able to get better performance in places by passing in `insts` as a vector.
This is because currently you are querying the database several times for each `inst`. Instead if you make more use of more `by` clauses and `in` rather than `=` you can go to the database once for all `insts`.

This can result in more memory being used at times so you'll need to monitor this. Possibly some memory heavy parts may still need to be broken down to `each insts`.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting `'stop` because your kdb system admins have a timeout on client queries.

`Not connected to kdb+ server` could indicate you are killing the process due to memory.

Split up your queries to the server by date and instrument to combine client side in a q process.

Answer (score 0):

Rianoc, Matt Moore,

Thank you very much for your help on this issue. I evnetually found a workaround by using Rkdb and looping across my insts elements in R instead of sending it to the server as you suggested @rianoc. I then do the processing for each inst alone and this works well although I think it is not a good practice. It should be possible to do it all on the server side I think. I was not able to do it yet, but if I find a way I'll let you know.